# GDB & C++: Printing vector of pointers to objects

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, stl, gdb

In my code, I have a STL vector which holds pointers to objects.
The reason why I coded like this is because I must manipulate the objects itself from different places.

```
std::vector<Object*> objects;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    Object* o = new Object(i);
    objects.push_back(o);
}
```

This code is assuming that Object is an object which takes in an integer as a constructor parameter. Assuming that I breakpoint with my GDB after the for loop ends, what do I have to do in order to view the objects within my vector easily?

When I do "p objects" it only lists the pointer addresses which is totally expected, but I want to see the integer variable that each object holds as well. I tried "p objects[0]" but this returns "Could not find operator[]".

Has anyone ran into this problem? or know how I can get around this?
My goal is to be able to look inside what objects actually hold from GDB when those object's pointers are stored in a STL vector.

Comment: I would suggest having a vector of smart pointers. And you might try `p *o`  or `p objects` in the `gdb` debugger.

Comment: I need to observe what is inside the vector of pointers to objects from different places, and doing "p objects" will show me all the addresses but they won't show me what is held within each object, and "p objects[0]" doesn't work either, saying "Could not find operator[]"

Comment: Recent versions of `gdb` and of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) i.e. of `g++` may help

Comment: @user3064869 Many answers suggest using a [pretty printer](https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport).

Comment: @remyabel I have this in my gdbinit, it tell me all the pointer addresses contained in the vector because it was coded to hold pointers to objects.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch I will try that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is certainly implemented defined, but for GCC, you can do:

```
print **(v._M_impl._M_start)@1
```

Where `v` refers to the vector, and `1` refers to the index. You need to dereference twice to get the value.

```
struct Object
{
    int n;
    Object(int n)
        : n(n) { }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Object*> v;
    v.push_back(new Object{42});
    v.size(); // where we breakpoint
    // release our memory at some point
}
```

And our test run:

```
(gdb) break 16
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400aae: file test.cpp, line 16.
(gdb) run
Starting program: a.out 

Breakpoint 1, main () at test.cpp:16
16      v.size(); // where we breakpoint
(gdb) print v
$1 = {<std::_Vector_base<Object*, std::allocator<Object*> >> = {
    _M_impl = {<std::allocator<Object*>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<Object*>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_start = 0x604030, _M_finish = 0x604038, _M_end_of_storage = 0x604038}}, <No data fields>}
(gdb) print **(v._M_impl._M_start)@1
$2 = {{n = 42}}
```

Comment: This is exactly sort of the answer I was looking for!! Is it possible to print from the beginning to end? instead of indexing one element?

Comment: @user3064869 Not sure, `print **(v._M_impl._M_start)@v.size()` seems close, but doesn't work for me.

Comment: Actually, showing all the elements accurately doesn't work. Only the first element seems valid and the rest of the element's fields have ridiculous values.

Comment: @user3064869 As a workaround, you can do `print **(v._M_impl._M_start + 1)`, `print **(v._M_impl._M_start + 2)`...

Comment: This works, but it must be typed out for all the entries of the vector. There is no standard method of printing a full vector of pointers to objects in one command? People don't run into this problem?

Comment: @user3064869 The other alternative is to do `set $POS = 0`, `print **(v._M_impl._M_start + ++$POS)`. But that requires you to repeat the command until you loop over all of them. Then you have to set $POS back to 0 if you want to do it again. I'm not sure if GDB has a real way of looping.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that prints the values one after another:

```
define pv
  set $pvPOS_ = 0
  while $arg0._M_impl._M_start + $pvPOS_ != $arg0._M_impl._M_finish 
    print **($arg0._M_impl._M_start + $pvPOS_)
    set $pvPOS_ = $pvPOS_ + 1
  end
end
```

Used as `pv my_vec`